# Missing Icons in Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome

Symbols are missing in the settings menu.
How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by missing symbol?

Comment: Personal - Hardware - System

Comment: I changed the image to make it clear

Comment: still dont get it... im sorry... mine here http://img.rc.my/X/systemsett.jpg

Comment: Inside the red circles. Seems like there should be an icon and is replaced by a not-found-icon

Comment: oh... icon... have you install any icon package?

Comment: Nope, no icon package. Is icon not the same as symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, open terminal and run this command.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Gnome'
```

To see the difference, run another command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Humanity'
```

And then hit (Alt + F2) and 'r' then 'ENTER'

Comment: no problem Sir! Enjoy Ubuntu!